# How to properly create a RollingFileAppender with AppenderComponentBuilder in log4j 2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I would like the user to choose the type of the appender(s) that will be created via a configurable option.

For example, let's say that I have a command line argument that controls the type of the appenders that will be created for that process. The user can choose one of these values: file,syslog, or both.

I would like to do this in a programmatic way, rather than using an external xml configuration file.

This is a simplified version of my attempt to create a logger with a syslog appender in a programmatic way.

```
// simplified version of a method that creates and returns a logger
// using AppenderComponentBuilder
static Logger createLogger()
{
        ConfigurationBuilder< BuiltConfiguration > builder =
                ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

        builder.setStatusLevel( Level.OFF );

        // create the syslog appender
        AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder =
                builder.newAppender( "syslogAppender", "Syslog" )
                .addAttribute( "protocol", "TCP" )
                .addAttribute( "host", "localhost" )
                .addAttribute( "port", 514 )
                .addAttribute( "facility", "LOCAL2" )
                .addAttribute( "immediateFlush", true )
                .addAttribute( "newLine", true );
        builder.add( appenderBuilder );

        // create the new logger
        builder.add( builder.newLogger( "TestLogger", Level.DEBUG )
                .add( builder.newAppenderRef( "syslogAppender" ) )
                .addAttribute( "additivity", false ) );

        builder.add( builder.newRootLogger( Level.DEBUG )
                .add( builder.newAppenderRef( "syslogAppender" ) ) );

        // Initialize the new configuration
        LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize( builder.build() );
        Logger logger = ctx.getLogger( "TestLogger" );
        return logger;
}
```

My questions:

1) Do you believe that this is the best way to use the log4j 2 API in order to programmatically create a logger and a syslog appender?

2) I would like to extend the above createLogger() method so that it will create the proper appenders depending on the user choice: file,syslog,both. The "file" option should create a Rolling file appender with a specific pattern layout, triggering policy, and rollover strategy. I tried to use the same log4j 2 API and use the AppenderComponentBuilder to do this, but I couldn't find a correct way of doing this. The only way I managed to programmatically do this was with the RollingFileAppender.createAppender() method, which is a real pain and makes it very difficult to allow me to create, on the fly, programmatically, a single logger with either a rolling file appender, a syslog appender or both (depending on the user input).

So, in essence, what I am looking for is the proper way to programmatically create a RollingFileAppender with a specific pattern layout, triggering policy, and rollover strategy using AppenderComponentBuilder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, this is the intended way to programmatically create a new configuration.
2. Here is an example of how to create a rolling file appender. Since Appenders can be configured with arbitrary components you use the generic ComponentBuilder to specify those plugins.

   ```
   ConfigurationBuilder< BuiltConfiguration > builder =
           ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

   builder.setStatusLevel( Level.ERROR);
   builder.setConfigurationName("RollingBuilder");
   // create the console appender
   AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").addAttribute("target",
           ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
   appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").
           addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"));
   builder.add( appenderBuilder );

   LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
           .addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n");
   ComponentBuilder triggeringPolicy = builder.newComponent("Policies")
           .addComponent(builder.newComponent("CronTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("schedule", "0 0 0 * * ?"))
           .addComponent(builder.newComponent("SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("size", "100M"));
   appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("rolling", "RollingFile")
           .addAttribute("fileName", "target/rolling.log")
           .addAttribute("filePattern", "target/archive/rolling-%d{MM-dd-yy}.log.gz")
           .add(layoutBuilder)
           .addComponent(triggeringPolicy);
   builder.add(appenderBuilder);

   // create the new logger
   builder.add( builder.newLogger( "TestLogger", Level.DEBUG )
           .add( builder.newAppenderRef( "rolling" ) )
           .addAttribute( "additivity", false ) );

   builder.add( builder.newRootLogger( Level.DEBUG )
           .add( builder.newAppenderRef( "rolling" ) ) );
   Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
   ```

Comment: One thing that is not clear to me is why do we have to have to link/associate the appender to both the new logger **and** to the new root logger? Also, why didn't you associated the console appender to the root logger as well? I experimented by not associating the rolling file appender to the root logger and my configuration still works.  Is there a specific reason when we have to (or we shouldn't) associate it with the root logger?

Comment: You don't have to associate the appender to both a specific logger and the root logger.  You associate whatever appender is appropriate to whatever logger you want, including the root.  The root logger is the default if you have loggers that don't match any other configured loggers. So generally you configure that for where you want things like general errors that might occur in any components you are using to go. If you don't configure the root logger with an appender all those events will be ignored.

Comment: This helped - it took me hours to get SmtpAppender working. I may have missed the documentation somewhere talking about plugin definitions. After trying the RollingFile, I realized that the code seems to add appender to the end of the plugin.