# How to switch programmatic logging configurations

Tags: java, log4j2

I am trying to use log4j version 2.11.1.
I have code that can successfully log to console or to a log file.  However, I want to start with one and switch to the other partway through the code.

The example at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html under "Programmatically Modifying the Current Configuration after Initialization" uses deprecated code, and I haven't been able to find another usable example.

```
public class testLogs {

  protected static Logger logger;

  private static void setupLogging(boolean useConsole) {
    if (useConsole) {
        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ERROR);
        builder.setConfigurationName("BuilderTest");
        builder.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL)
                .addAttribute("level", Level.DEBUG));
        AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").addAttribute("target",
                ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
        appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
                .addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"));
        appenderBuilder.add(builder.newFilter("MarkerFilter", Filter.Result.DENY, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL)
                .addAttribute("marker", "FLOW"));
        builder.add(appenderBuilder);
        builder.add(builder.newLogger("org.apache.logging.log4j", Level.DEBUG)
                .add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")).addAttribute("additivity", false));
        builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.ERROR).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")));
        LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
        ctx.updateLoggers();
    } else {
        // from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969778/10863944
        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory
                .newConfigurationBuilder();

        builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ERROR);
        builder.setConfigurationName("RollingBuilder");
        // create the console appender
        AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender(
                "Stdout", "CONSOLE").addAttribute("target",
                ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
        appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute(
                "pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"));
        builder.add(appenderBuilder);

        LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout(
                "PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern",
                "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n");
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        ComponentBuilder triggeringPolicy = builder
                .newComponent("Policies")
                .addComponent(
                        builder.newComponent("CronTriggeringPolicy")
                                .addAttribute("schedule", "0 0 0 * * ?"))
                .addComponent(
                        builder.newComponent("SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy")
                                .addAttribute("size", "100M"));
        appenderBuilder = builder
                .newAppender("rolling", "RollingFile")
                .addAttribute("fileName", "logs/mylog.log")
                .addAttribute("filePattern",
                        "logs/mylog-%d{MM-dd-yy}.log.gz").add(layoutBuilder)
                .addComponent(triggeringPolicy);
        builder.add(appenderBuilder);

        // create the new logger
        builder.add(builder.newLogger("TestLogger", Level.DEBUG)
                .add(builder.newAppenderRef("rolling"))
                .addAttribute("additivity", false));

        builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.DEBUG).add(
                builder.newAppenderRef("rolling")));
        LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
        ctx.updateLoggers();
    }
    logger = LogManager.getLogger();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    setupLogging(true); // use the console
    logger.info("logging should be on the console");
    setupLogging(false); // do not use the console
    logger.info("logging should be in the log file");
  }

}
```

I expected the first log message to be on the console and the second log message to be in the file.
Actual results are that all output is on the console, and the file is empty.

Comment: You should elaborate a bit more what you are trying to achieve (edit your question). There are alternative approaches with both console and file logging active but filter the output so that you don't have to "exchange" the complete log config. In the end such a config may be easier and more robust.

Comment: I don't know what else to add to my question.  A user may have started my program from the wrong directory, in which case I test for that and do not want the log file created.  In that case, I want the logging to go to the console.  Once all the setup is verified and complete, I want logging to go to the appropriate file.

Comment: I don't use log4j, but the `Configurator` class looks to me like something that is initialized *once* when the logger is first loaded.  I don't think you can use it to change the configuration once it's set.

Comment: This answer says to use `LogManager.resetConfiguration();` to change configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592399/change-log4j-properties-at-runtime

Comment: Thanks @markspace ... unfortunately, when I try to add `LogManager.resetConfiguration()` to my code, I get this: `The method resetConfiguration() is undefined for the type LogManager`

Comment: Are you using the right log manager?  Log4j, not the built-in java.utils class?

Comment: I have `import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;`.

Comment: I added `LogManager.shutdown();` at the beginning of each section of the if statement.  That works, except I get the unneed error "ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to th
e console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j
 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for ins
tructions on how to configure Log4j 2".  So now if I can just get rid of the error, I am all set.

Comment: Got it thanks to your help @markspace.  Thanks :-) Will post solution in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments my understanding is that the following is your desired outcome:

> A user may have started my program from the wrong directory, in which
>   case I test for that and do not want the log file created. In that
>   case, I want the logging to go to the console. Once all the setup is
>   verified and complete, I want logging to go to the appropriate file.

The main reason **not** to go with a programmatic solution is that it makes your code dependent on log4j2 implementation details. If later on the implementation changes and you wish to use the latest version of log4j2 then your code must also change. This makes upgrading to a newer version of log4j2 harder and more work for you.

Rather than alter the configuration programmatically you could use the [RoutingAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) similar to how it's used in [one of the examples](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files) on the [log4j2 FAQ page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html). This way you're using features intended for public use. Your code is not affected by the internal implementation of log4j2 because you're simply using the provided public interface.

Here is some sample java code that generates log messages:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;

public class Log4j2DiffAppenderPerCtxVarMain {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //This is before validation
        LOG.info("This should appear in console only.");

        //Check if everything is valid then add the routing key
        ThreadContext.put("ROUTINGKEY", "anyValueYouWant");
        LOG.info("This should appear in the log file");
    }
}
```

Here is the log4j2 config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Routing name="myAppender">
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}">

                <!-- This route is chosen if ThreadContext has no value for key ROUTINGKEY. -->
                <Route key="$${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}">
                    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                        <PatternLayout
                            pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
                    </Console>
                </Route>

                <!-- This route is chosen if ThreadContext has a value for ROUTINGKEY -->
                <Route>
                    <RollingFile name="RollingLog" fileName="myLogFile.log"
                        filePattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
                        <PatternLayout
                            pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6"
                                modulate="true" />
                            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
                        </Policies>
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="myAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The result of the above is that first log message appears only in console as expected and the second appears only in the log file.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what all of this you are doing but whatever you want to do from your description can be done by this easy steps,

```
// File Appender setup
FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender();
fileAppender.setName("filelogging");
fileAppender.setFile("filelogging.log");
fileAppender.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
fileAppender.setAppend(true);
fileAppender.activateOptions();

// add appender
Logger.getLogger("filelogging").addAppender(fileAppender);
// get instance of logger
Logger fileLogger = Logger.getLogger("filelogging");

// Console Appender setup
ConsoleAppender consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender();
consoleAppender.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
consoleAppender.activateOptions();

// add appender
Logger.getLogger("console").addAppender(consoleAppender);
// get instance of logger
Logger consoleLogger = Logger.getLogger("console");

// use
fileLogger.warn("Hey this will print in file.");
consoleLogger.warn("Hey this will print in console.");
```

At the end we have successfully setup two loggers, And by their defined name you can use them to switch back and forth wherever you want.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks JBaba, this is very elegant.  Unfortunately it did not address my needs.  I would have had to wrap all of the logging statements in if statements to check which logger to use.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @markspace for getting me to look in the right direction.  Here is the solution if anybody else should need such:

```
public class testLogs {

    protected static Logger logger;
    private static boolean logInitialized = false;

    private static void setupLogging(boolean useConsole) {
        if (logInitialized) {
            LogManager.shutdown();
        }
        if (useConsole) {
            ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ERROR);
            builder.setConfigurationName("BuilderTest");
            builder.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL)
                    .addAttribute("level", Level.DEBUG));
            AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").addAttribute("target",
                    ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
            appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
                    .addAttribute("pattern", "%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"));
            appenderBuilder.add(builder.newFilter("MarkerFilter", Filter.Result.DENY, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL)
                    .addAttribute("marker", "FLOW"));
            builder.add(appenderBuilder);
            builder.add(builder.newLogger("org.apache.logging.log4j", Level.DEBUG)
                    .add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")).addAttribute("additivity", false));
            builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.ERROR).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")));
            LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
            ctx.updateLoggers();
        } else {
            // from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969778/10863944
            ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory
                    .newConfigurationBuilder();

            builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ERROR);
            builder.setConfigurationName("RollingBuilder");
            // create the console appender
            AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender(
                    "Stdout", "CONSOLE").addAttribute("target",
                    ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
            appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute(
                    "pattern", "%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"));
            builder.add(appenderBuilder);

            LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout(
                    "PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern",
                    "%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level: %msg%n");
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            ComponentBuilder triggeringPolicy = builder
                    .newComponent("Policies")
                    .addComponent(
                            builder.newComponent("CronTriggeringPolicy")
                                    .addAttribute("schedule", "0 0 0 * * ?"))
                    .addComponent(
                            builder.newComponent("SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy")
                                    .addAttribute("size", "100M"));
            appenderBuilder = builder
                    .newAppender("rolling", "RollingFile")
                    .addAttribute("fileName", "logs/myfile.log")
                    .addAttribute("filePattern",
                            "logs/myfile-%d{MM-dd-yy}.log.gz").add(layoutBuilder)
                    .addComponent(triggeringPolicy);
            builder.add(appenderBuilder);

            // create the new logger
            builder.add(builder.newLogger("TestLogger", Level.DEBUG)
                    .add(builder.newAppenderRef("rolling"))
                    .addAttribute("additivity", false));

            builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.DEBUG).add(
                    builder.newAppenderRef("rolling")));
            LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
            ctx.updateLoggers();
        }
        logger = LogManager.getLogger();
        logInitialized = true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setupLogging(true); // use the console
        logger.info("logging should be on the console");
        setupLogging(false); // do not use the console
        logger.info("logging should be in the log file");
    }
}
```

Thanks!  :-)