# log4j2 migration - How to create a SyslogAppender with a PatternLayout

Tags: log4j, log4j2

Migrating from log4j1 to log4j2.

What I want to replace

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MySysLogLogger.class);
String _address = _server.getHostAndPort();
                
SyslogAppender _syslogAppender = new SyslogAppender(new PatternLayout("%p: %m"),
                        SyslogAppender.LOG_SYSLOG);
_syslogAppender.setSyslogHost(_address);
logger.addAppender(_syslogAppender);
```

I have found two possible log4j2 approaches (other than doing in XML config - which I don't want)

Approach 1 - So close, but cannot find a way to add or associate the PatternLayout

```
SyslogAppender _syslogAppender = (SyslogAppender)SyslogAppender.newBuilder().withHost(_address).build();
```

Approach 2 - Seems like I can configure all items, but can't get a SyslogAppender object back out if it. (Based on [How to properly create a RollingFileAppender with AppenderComponentBuilder in log4j 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904304/how-to-properly-create-a-rollingfileappender-with-appendercomponentbuilder-in-lo))

```
ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> configurationBuilder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

AppenderComponentBuilder appenderComponentBuilder = configurationBuilder.newAppender("Syslog", "Syslog");
LayoutComponentBuilder standardLayout = configurationBuilder.newLayout("PatternLayout");
standardLayout.addAttribute("pattern", pPatternLayout);
appenderComponentBuilder.add(standardLayout);
```

The examples I have found show only that you can add it with something like this

```
RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLogger = configurationBuilder.newRootLogger(Level.WARN);
rootLogger.add(configurationBuilder.newAppenderRef("Syslog"));
configurationBuilder.add(rootLogger);
// ... more attribute configuration    
Configurator.initialize(configurationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: You can't. In Log4j 2.x the `SyslogAppender` does not accept a layout or more precisely it only accepts a layout that formats the entire message (`SyslogLayout` or `Rfc5424Layout`). See the bug report [LOG4J2-3359](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3359#comment-17480702).

Comment: Regarding how to use your two approaches, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70507856/11748454).